# How do I get the output of WWW:Curl::Easy into a variable in Perl

Tags: perl, curl

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);    
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);    
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/login.php");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=usertest&pass=passwdtest");
$curl->perform();
```

It will printout like this.
How do I get the output into a variable from perform function?

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found  Cache-Control:
> no-cache, must-revalidate  Expires:
> Sat, 11 Jan 200 05:00:00 GMT
> Location: ?cookiecheck=1
> Content-type: text/html  Date: Thu, 28
> Apr 2011 09:15:57 GMT  Server:
> xxxx/0.1  Content-Length: 0
> Connection: Keep-Alive  Set-Cookie:
> auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
> expires=Sat, 27-Apr-2013 09:15:57 GMT;
> path=/; domain=.example.com

Answer (score 2):

I agree with PacoRG that you most likely should look into using a module from the `LWP::` space. Since you have more specific needs I would recommend the [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent).

That said if you really need to get something which is being printed to instead be stored in a variable, we can play some games with deeper Perl magic.

```
# setopt method calls here

## the variable you want to store your data in
my $variable;

{
  ## open a "filehandle" to that variable
  open my $output, '>', \$variable;

  ## then redirect STDOUT (where stuff goes when it is printed) to the filehandle $output
  local *STDOUT = $output;

  ## when you do the perform action, the results should be stored in your variable
  $curl->perform();
}

## since you redirected with a 'local' command, STDOUT is restored outside the block
## since $output was opened lexically (with my), its filehandle is closed when the block ends

# do stuff with $variable here
```

Perhaps `WWW::Curl::Easy` has a better way of doing this, since I don't know that module's commands I have provided you with a hack that will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? May be [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple) is what you need...

Answer (score 0):

Over 11 years later, I hope this helps:

```
my $response;
sub write_data($$$$) {
        $response .= shift;
        return length($response);
}
# ... curl setup
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,\&write_data);
# ... curl perform
print "$response\n"
```

Note that `curl` will pass in smaller buffers/chunks repeatedly into the specified callback (`write_data`) so if you want the entire response, it's important to append the buffer to the resultant variable via `.=`.